# Getting window list in Xvfb server

Tags: linux, debian, x11, xvfb

I'm trying to get the window list in a Xvfb server in a debian squeeze machine.
What I'm doing is:

```
$ Xvfb :2&
$ DISPLAY=:2; wmctrl -l
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot get client list properties. (_NET_CLIENT_LIST or _WIN_CLIENT_LIST)
```

Is this normal or am I missing something?

Thanks!!

Comment: what is result of `DISPLAY=:2 xwininfo -tree -root`?

Comment: The result it

    `xwininfo: Window id: 0xe8 (the root window) (has no name)

    Root window id: 0xe8 (the root window) (has no name)
    Parent window id: 0x0 (none)
     0 children.`

Comment: I'm also getting this message when launching Xvfb: `SELinux: Disabled on system, not enabling in X server`

Comment: @AndreySidorov thanks for the answer!!. Your command works. And now I understand that wmctrl -l still doesn't work because I haven't launched a window manager in :2. Once I launch it, there's support for _NET_CLIENT_LIST

Comment: @sgimeno: nice that you got it working. I run into the same problem. Could you elaborate on how you launched which window manager?

Comment: @richelbilderbeek Sure. _NET_CLIENT_LIST or _WIN_CLIENT_LIST properties are set by windows managers in the root window to keep the list of windows managed by the window manager. So in my case the problem was that there was no window manager launched in the DISPLAY :2. To launch it, you can do (for fluxbox for example): `DISPLAY=:2; fluxbox`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Im my case xfce-panel was not configured.
Finally I executed:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/xfce4-panel
```

This solved the problem (I did not need this panel). 
This is a dirty hack. The proper approach is configuring the panel.